# Can't access Sidekiq web UI on Heroku

Tags: heroku, sidekiq

I've  configured my rails app to include Sidekiq and I've added the appropriate routes to see the web UI. I can see the sidekiq dashboard in development but I can't see it in production. This is my `routes.rb` file:

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  ...
  authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.super_user? } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
```

I added authentication per the specifications in the [documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring). I also added the sinatra gem to my gemfile:

```
# Use Sidekiq for background job processing
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
```

On my local development server I can access the page fine. However in Heroku I'm first prompted to login then I'm directed to a 404 error page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Devise for authentication, try wrapping your mounting of Sidekiq under `devise_scope`:

```
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user, lambda { |u| u.super_user? } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
end
```

Comment: @Jarrel09 Can you test the code without the requirement of a user needing to be a super user, and if that works, double check that you've populated your database on Heroku with roles and that your user in that database has the correct roles.